# Click Event for Notification in xamarin.froms

Tags: xamarin.forms, notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I use Dependency Service For Implements the Notitfication in Android and Ios App.
How to use Click Event for Notification in xamarin.forms?
for example when I click in Notification Open The xaml Page in PCl Project...

Comment: Do you mean when user click the notification, you want to push to a particular page in forms?

Comment: yes exactly and I don't use Remote Notifcaion in xamrin.forms I use SignalR for Send And Recive Notification

Comment: @ErWave how did you move forward with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link is useful for you in that I mentioned every thing

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100056/how-to-open-a-different-xaml-page-on-push-notification-click-event

Answer (score 0):

Use MessagingCenter, set ContentPage type or url for MessagingCenter.Send, then MessagingCenter.Subscribe & load

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Comment: your solution is good but , I wish when I click on Notification Send User To Xaml Page...this Solution Send User to xaml Page when Notification Recied